# Piling up particles

Tags: particles

[image: Here is what I have so far. The glitter planes are not laying flat, how would I accomplish this?]I have created particles to simulate piles of glitter. I am not able to get them to pile up. How would I accomplish this? This is what I have so far.
[image: screenshot of particles]

My overall objective is the recreate in 3D the slow-motion sequence of a glitter bomb as in this [video](https://youtu.be/h4T_LlK1VE4?t=360) (the sequence starts around the six minute mark).
[image: glitter bomb]

I appreciate any help towards this goal!

Comment: Most likey done using force fields to effect particles. You can add a force field with SHIFT A > Force Field

Answer (score 1):

A ***Harmonic* force field** attracts particles nearby and forms a sphere of them that shrinks to a point over time. You can change the value *Shape* to `Every Point` to scatter them all over the surface of an object.

So, if you literally want to pile up particles you can use a *Cone* object. Add a *Remesh* modifier to it, and set remesh method to `Blocks`. This is just to create more vertices because the default cone has only one vert at the top and some at the bottom. Since 'Every Point' means every vertex we need more of them.

In the *Physics* tab, add a *Force Field* to the cone, set *Shape* to `Every Point`.
Turn off *Field Weights > Gravity* (`0`) in the *Particle Properties* tab for a better result. Run the animation.

[image: a pile of particles]
<sup>A pile of particles. The plane is the emitter</sup>

For the detonation of the glitter bomb, turn on *Gravity* (keyframe). Keyframe the *Force Field Type*, and set it to `Turbolence` after a while. At the same frame, set *Shape* to `Surface`. That's important if you don't want to freeze Blender.
 Increase the *Strength* value if needed. Keep in mind that you need to keyframe 3 values if you want to have a value constant over time and then instantly go up.

Have fun!

Comment: I have something closer to what I am looking for but the planes for the glitter do not lay flat. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I would like to upload my Blender file for review, if I can.

Comment: You can upload it to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and add the generated link to your question. It's removed after about 5 months. Or use https://blend-exchange.com/ to save it "forever"

Comment: Great! I just did. Let me know if you can access it.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/23b34b359dd04a7ea05aa496ae901209 does this work

Comment: Hey, Blunder did you get a chance to look at the file I uploaded?

Comment: Yes. If you want to create a heap from a plane you don't need a *Remesh* modifier better use a *Solidify* modifier to give it some thickness. The *ParticleSettings* modifier must go after the *Solidify* modifier on the modifier stack and you need to check the *Use Modifier Stack* checkbox in the particle settings (or apply the Solifier modifier). Also, use Newtonian particles not Boid in Particle-Physics. Boids are for moths, birds & fishes. I've messed around with the settings but still not sure how to prevent the bouncing of the particles. I keyframed the Damp value.

Comment: Here is the file with the changes: https://pasteall.org/blend/1985f442a3184644b14749b907958ac3

Comment: Hey Blunder, could you look at the file I uploaded to see why my particles are not oriented flat toward the base plane

Comment: sure, do you have a download link?

Comment: Yes, https://pasteall.org/blend/1985f442a3184644b14749b907958ac3

Comment: Thanks, look forward to your assessment